# Flask SQLAlchemy paginate over objects in a relationship

Tags: python, pagination, sqlalchemy

So I have two models: Article and Tag, and a m2m relationship which is properly set.

I have a route of the kind 'articles/tag/' and I would like to display only those articles related to that tag

I have sorted out this problem already but I am looking for a more elegant solution including **pagination** but I am not able to use `paginate`over the articles list because it's not a `queryset`

I need a queryset of all articles linked to a certain tag. I have tried `order_by` in many different ways and failed miserably.. I wasnt able to find something useful in the docs, any ideas?

Comment: You can try configuring [`lazy="dynamic"`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders) on the relationship. Caveats apply.

Comment: The thing is that from one side, Article, if I do article.tags it returns me a BaseQuery but in the other way is a list of objects. I am new to SQLAlchemy so I have no idea why is this happening

Comment: That's the backref. You can configure `lazy="dynamic"` on the backref too.

Comment: Thank you I changed it from:
    `articles = db.relationship('Article', secondary=tagged, backref=db.backref('tags', lazy='dynamic'))`

To:
    `articles = db.relationship('Article', secondary=tagged, backref=db.backref('tags', lazy='dynamic'), lazy="dynamic")`

Seems like I was missing the second `lazy`

Answer (score 1):

While OP's problem was `lazy="dynamic"`, I ran into this issue with a relationship which was already using that. In my case, the problem turned out to be that I was using `relationship()` imported directly from `sqlalchemy.orm`. Instead, I needed to use `db.relationship()` to get [the version of the method](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/68) wrapped by Flask-SQLAlchemy.